# Change Scan settings via C#

Tags: c#, image-scanner

I have scan via "wiaacmgr.exe" with process.start and scanned form.After scanned form its stored at pictures folder but i want to store that form my desired place like D:\images. via C# program.

```
 Process myProcess = new Process();
 string Exepath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Scanexe"];
 myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 myProcess.StartInfo.FileName =Exepath+ "Wiaacmgr.exe";
 myProcess.Start();
```

After scan i want to save image my desired place.

Any Idea Please..

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Starting a process limits you to setting command line parameters. Unless your `Wiaacmgr.exe` supports parameters then I don't see how you could change the target folder.

Comment: Check this out: https://superuser.com/questions/801202/how-to-change-the-default-folder-used-for-documents-scanned-with-windows-fax-and

Comment: Hi @PepitoSh: Thanks for your response. i want to change folder location via program.

Comment: @JohnEphraimTugado: thanks for your response. Yes. I am checking wiaacmgr.exe support parameter regards change file save path. i am not getting any idea..

Comment: The registry settings are there for you to set from your code.

Comment: @PepitoSh: Client system they have set default scan settings. so i can't change that. I want to create one new folder and save image that folder.

Comment: @PepitoSh: as per your link user33758 answer : is Created new folder link path and copy the same files here. but my problem is i don't know default scan location. if i know default scan location, i will use registery settings as per your suggestion